# Improve efficiency of modifying object properties in a list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a list of custom objects that I am working with.  I need to find matching objects, and save two attributes to the object, and move on.  I can't help but think that my method of working with these objects is sub-optimal.  Given I am working with large volumes of data (in this instance a list with ~ 10000 objects, but in other instances significantly larger), I would appreciate any information that might help me optimize the process.

```
List<WebListingVerification> listings = new List<WebListingVerification>(); //This list is fully populated, and is actually passed into the function.

string sku = reader["vsr_sku"].ToString();
string vendorName = reader["v_name"].ToString();
string vendorSku = reader["vsr_vendor_sku"].ToString();

WebListingVerification listing = listings.Find(x => x.SKU == sku);
if(listing != null)
{
    listings.Remove(listing);
    listing.Vendor = vendorName;
    listing.VendorSKU = vendorSku;
    listings.Add(listing);
}
```

As you can see above, I first remove the listing, then edit it, and then re-add it.  I imagine there is a way to safely edit the object in the list without running Remove / Add which would help a great deal, but I can't seem to find how to do it.  I'm not sure if you could do a compound function off of the listings.Find call (`listings.Find(x => x.SKU == sku).Vendor = "vendor"`) but it would be unsafe, as there will be null returns in this circumstance anyways so..

Any help optimizing this would be greatly appreciated.

***Edit***

Thank you for the comments, I did not understand the fact that the result of the List.Find function call is in fact a pointer to the object in the list, and not a copy of the object.  This clears up my issue!

In addition, thank you for the additional answers.  I was looking for a simple improvement, predominantly to remove the Add / Remove routines, but the additional answers give me some good ideas on how to write these routines in the future which may net some significant performance improvements.  I've been focused on reporting tasks in the past few months, so this example snippet is very similar to probably 100 different routines where I am gathering data from various source databases.  Again, I very much appreciate the input.

Comment: The only thing accomplished by removing and re-adding the item is to move it from where it is in the list to the end.  Do you actually need to do that?

Comment: when the item is returned out of the list, is it still associated with the list.. ie when I modify the item returned by find, it is actually the same object as the object in the list?  I come from a c background so.. my brain says when you use the equals sign, it effectively makes a copy of the object

Comment: As @Servy said, there's no need to remove and re-add the item unless you actually wanted to move it in the list. That's the part that's going to be slow. If you are doing that to try to force some kind of binding update, then it would help if you added some more context. They is probably a better way.

Comment: @NateM. *ie when I modify the item returned by find, it is actually the same object as the object in the list?* Yes. For reference types you are copying the reference. So `listing` still points to the same object as the reference in your list.

Comment: Ok. so, it sounds like when I use a List.Find, I need to act like the resultant object is really a reference to an object in the list.  If that is correct, you have both corrected my understanding and solved my issue.

Comment: @NateM. You're removing a pointer to an object, dereferencing that pointer in order to mutate a few properties, and then adding the pointer back into the list.  Thus the only purpose of the list mutation is to move the pointer from wherever it was to the end.

Comment: *I need to act like the resultant object is really a reference to an object in the list.* You don't need to *act like*, because that's what it really is.

Comment: awesome.  Ok.. I'm still pretty new to C# so I'm not used to how certain types can mask the fact that you're actually working with a pointer / reference.  That answers my question.  Thanks to you both

Comment: @NateM. Look up reference vs value types in C# and it should help clear things up.

Comment: @Nate How big is your `listings` list?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The question specifically says 10k items.

Comment: Does sku field is unique in all cases?

Comment: At this point in code, the SKU field in listings should denote a unique object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed up the lookup you could first convert your list into a dictionary. Note though if your update method is a method, you should not do the conversion inside the method, but outside the update loop.

```
var dictionary = listings.ToDictionary(l => l.SKU);
```

And get the item from the dictionary with the *sku* value.

```
WebListingVerification listing;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(sku, out listing))
{
    listing.Vendor = vendorName;
    listing.VendorSKU = vendorSku;
}
```

Comment: If there's any chance that a given `sku` might not be in the dictionary, then you should use `ContainsKey` to check before trying to access it.

Comment: There's no point in passing an identity projection to the second parameter to `ToDictionary`, just don't provide a second parameter if you don't need an element projection.  And note that the dictionary indexer throws if the key doesn't exist; it doesn't return `null`.

Comment: @MattBurland No, you should use `TryGetValue`.

Comment: I would need some indication of null, since a null return will occur in this routine.  I presume there are still some improvements over List.Find even if using ContainsKey?  Or TryGetValue for that matter =) hard keeping up with the back and forth

Comment: Updated the answer based on the comments.

Comment: My focus was originally on optimizing while still continuing the use of a list.  A dictionary would be as easy implementation wise, and seems to have performance advantages if handled properly.  Accepting as answer, since the post addresses both the sub-optimal function calls Add / Remove, but likewise improves upon the data structure I was using.  Also, very easy to implement =)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class WebListingVerification
    {
        public string Sku { get; set; }

        public string VendorName { get; set; }

        public string VendorSku { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListingManager : IEnumerable <WebListingVerification>
    {
        private Dictionary<string, WebListingVerification> _webListDictionary;

        public ListingManager(IEnumerable <WebListingVerification> existingListings)
        {
            if (existingListings == null)
                _webListDictionary = new Dictionary<string, WebListingVerification>();
            else
                _webListDictionary = existingListings.ToDictionary(a => a.Sku);
        }

        public void AddOrUpdate (string sku, string vendorName, string vendorSku)
        {
            WebListingVerification verification;
            if (false == _webListDictionary.TryGetValue (sku, out verification))
                _webListDictionary[sku] = verification = new WebListingVerification();

            verification.VendorName = vendorName;
            verification.VendorSku = vendorSku;
        }

        public IEnumerator<WebListingVerification> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var item in _webListDictionary)
                yield return item.Value;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your items are unique, might I suggest a `HashSet<T>`?

```
HashSet<WebListingVerification> listings = new HashSet<WebListingVerification>();

string sku = reader["vsr_sku"].ToString();
string vendorName = reader["v_name"].ToString();
string vendorSku = reader["vsr_vendor_sku"].ToString();

if(listings.Contains(listing))
{
    listings.Remove(listing);
    listing.Vendor = vendorName;
    listing.VendorSKU = vendorSku;
    listings.Add(listing);
}
```

You'd have to roll your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface on the `WebListingVerification` object and match on the SKU, which I assume is unique.

```
public class WebListingVerification : IEqualityComparer<WeblistingVerification>
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(WebListingVerification obj, WebListingVerification obj2)
    {
        if (obj == null && obj2 == null)
            return true;
        else if (obj == null | obj2 == null)
            return false;
        else if (obj.Sku == obj2.Sku)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(WebListingVerification obj)
    {
        return Sku.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

`HashSet.Contains()` performance is phenomenal on large datasets like this.

Comment: I was almost sure but to be 100% sure, i've decompiled with a tool both Dictionary and HashSet and it confirmed me that Dictionary.ContainsKey algorithm is 99.9999% the same as HashSet.Contains There are just a few things that are done more in Dictionary such as checking for null for incomming key parameter but nothing that can make a difference from performance point of view. I don't see the point of what you suggested, for me this smells like over engineering.

Comment: @GeorgeLica, correct, I just ran some benchmarks and a Dictionary and HashSet are virtually identical in performance. In fact, a dictionary is a smidge bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove and add back the object into the list. Just;

```
if(listing != null)
{
    listing.Vendor = vendorName;
    listing.VendorSKU = vendorSku;
}
```

Comment: I'm in agreement, but it's possible that during their operations they want the newly updated item at the very end of the collection.